# Collision detection not working in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a game at the moment and I am experiencing problems with collision detection. I am making an end of level block but it can not detect if the player is standing on it to change to level 2. The collision detection for the block is found in player.updater(). As well as this the block is a class and in a group called endPlatform to allow the collision detection to work. The game runs perfectly fine however it can not detect when the Player hits Endplatform. I get no errors which show up.

EndPlatform:

```
class EndPlatform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, display):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("endPlatform.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        display.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

Player:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Is it touching the floor?
        self.standing = True
        # Rendering image and creating some variables
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Slime.png")
        self.sprite_x_change = 0
        self.sprite_y_change = 0
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = 460
        self.rect.x = 120
    # Mobility: Left, right, up and stop
    def move_right(self):
        self.sprite_x_change = 8

    def move_left(self):
        self.sprite_x_change = -8

    def move_up(self, platform):
        if self.standing ==  True:
            self.sprite_y_change = -25
            self.standing = False
    def stop(self):
        self.sprite_x_change = 0

    def sprint(self):
        self.sprite_x_change += 10

    def updater(self, platforms, powerups, score, endPlatform):
        self.gravity()
        self.rect.x += self.sprite_x_change
        self.standing = False
        platforms_hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, platforms, False)
        for blocks in platforms_hit:
            if self.sprite_x_change > 0:
                self.rect.right = blocks.rect.left

            elif self.sprite_x_change < 0:
                self.rect.left = blocks.rect.right

        self.rect.y += self.sprite_y_change

        platforms_hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, platforms, False)
        for blocks in platforms_hit:
            # Going down
            if self.sprite_y_change > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = blocks.rect.top - 1
                self.standing = True
            # Going up
            elif self.sprite_y_change < 0:
                self.rect.top = blocks.rect.bottom
                self.standing = False

            self.sprite_y_change = 0

        coins_hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, powerups, True)
        if len(coins_hit) > 0:
            score.add()
        endLevel = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, endPlatform, True)
        if len(endLevel) > 0:
            score.add()
```

All the code:

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.font.init()
# Colours + Global constants
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0,  0, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RANDOM = (12, 211, 123)
WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600
SIZE = (WIDTH, HEIGHT)
AGENT = pygame.font.SysFont("Agent Orange", 30)


# CLASSES
# Block is the common platform
class EndPlatform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, display):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("endPlatform.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        display.blit(self.image, self.rect)




class Coins(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, display):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("hud_coins.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        display.blit(self.image, self.rect)



class Score:
    def __init__(self):
        self.score = 0

    def msgs(self, msg, colour, display):
        screen_text = AGENT.render(msg, True, colour)
        display.blit(screen_text, [0, 0])

    def add(self):
        self.score += 1


class Monster(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, length, height, colour):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([length, height])
        self.image.fill(colour)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        # Setting Y coordinates
        self.rect.y = HEIGHT - 80

    def jump(self):
        self.rect.y = -10


class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, length, height, colour):
        super().__init__()
        # Making image
        self.image = pygame.Surface([length, height])
        self.image.fill(colour)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        # Setting Y coordinates
        self.rect.y = 468


class Platform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, display, x_screen, y_screen, x_sheet, y_sheet, height, length):
        super().__init__()

        self.tiles = pygame.image.load("tiles_spritesheet.png")

        self.image = self.tiles.subsurface(pygame.Rect(x_sheet, y_sheet, height, length))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(x=x_screen, y=y_screen)



class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Is it touching the floor?
        self.standing = True
        # Rendering image and creating some variables
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Slime.png")
        self.sprite_x_change = 0
        self.sprite_y_change = 0
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = 460
        self.rect.x = 120
    # Mobility: Left, right, up and stop
    def move_right(self):
        self.sprite_x_change = 8

    def move_left(self):
        self.sprite_x_change = -8

    def move_up(self, platform):
        if self.standing ==  True:
            self.sprite_y_change = -25
            self.standing = False
    def stop(self):
        self.sprite_x_change = 0

    def sprint(self):
        self.sprite_x_change += 10

    def updater(self, platforms, powerups, score, endPlatform):
        self.gravity()
        self.rect.x += self.sprite_x_change
        self.standing = False
        platforms_hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, platforms, False)
        for blocks in platforms_hit:
            if self.sprite_x_change > 0:
                self.rect.right = blocks.rect.left

            elif self.sprite_x_change < 0:
                self.rect.left = blocks.rect.right

        self.rect.y += self.sprite_y_change

        platforms_hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, platforms, False)
        for blocks in platforms_hit:
            # Going down
            if self.sprite_y_change > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = blocks.rect.top - 1
                self.standing = True
            # Going up
            elif self.sprite_y_change < 0:
                self.rect.top = blocks.rect.bottom
                self.standing = False

            self.sprite_y_change = 0

        coins_hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, powerups, True)
        if len(coins_hit) > 0:
            score.add()
        endLevel = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, endPlatform, True)
        if len(endLevel) > 0:
            score.add()

    def gravity(self):
        self.sprite_y_change += 3


class Level:
    def __init__(self):
        # Creating groups
        self.endPlatform = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.powerups = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.all_things = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.platforms = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.entities = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.shift_x = 0
        self.shift_y = 0

    def updater(self, display, score):
        self.all_things.draw(display)
        score.msgs("Score: " + str(score.score), RED, display)


    def scroll_x(self, shift_x_change):
        self.shift_x += shift_x_change
        for platform in self.entities:
            platform.rect.x += shift_x_change

    def scroll_y(self, shift_y_change):
        self.shift_y += shift_y_change
        for platform in self.entities:
            platform.rect.y += shift_y_change



class Level01(Level):
    def __init__(self, player1, monster, display):
        # Initialise level1
        super().__init__()
        # Level01 things
        block = Block(245, 3, BLACK)
        Level.all_things = self.all_things
        self.sprites.add(player1, monster)
        self.platforms.add(block)
        self.all_things.add(player1, block, monster)
        self.entities.add(block)

        theLevel = []

        level = [[600, 400, 648, 0, 70, 70],
                 [740, 320, 648, 0, 70, 70],
                 [380, 400, 648, 0, 70, 70],
                 [900, 280, 648, 0, 70, 70],
                 [1200, 530, 648, 0, 70, 70],
                 [1350, 450, 648, 0, 70, 70],
                 [1500, 550, 648, 0, 70, 70],
                 [1680, 500, 648, 0, 70, 70],
                 ]

        for platform in theLevel:
            block = Block(platform[0], platform[1], RED)
            block.rect.x = platform[2]
            block.rect.y = platform[3]
            self.platforms.add(block)
            self.all_things.add(block)
            self.entities.add(block)
        for goodPlatform in level:
            platform = Platform(display, goodPlatform[0], goodPlatform[1], goodPlatform[2], goodPlatform[3], goodPlatform[4], goodPlatform[5])
            self.platforms.add(platform)
            self.all_things.add(platform)
            self.entities.add(platform)
        for n in range(1):
            coin = Coins(display)
            coin.rect.x = random.randint(0, WIDTH*3)
            coin.rect.y = 400
            self.all_things.add(coin)
            self.entities.add(coin)
            self.powerups.add(coin)
            platforms_hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(coin, self.entities, False)
            for hit in platforms_hit:
                coin.rect.x = random.randrange(0, WIDTH*3)
        finalPlatform = EndPlatform(display)
        finalPlatform.rect.x = 1900
        finalPlatform.rect.y = 420
        self.all_things.add(finalPlatform)
        self.entities.add(finalPlatform)
        self.platforms.add(finalPlatform)
        self.endPlatform.add(finalPlatform)


class Level02(Level):
    def __init__(self, player1, monster):
        super().__init__()
        # Level01 things
        block = Block(245, 3, BLACK)
        Level.all_things = self.all_things
        self.sprites.add(player1, monster)
        self.platforms.add(block)
        self.all_things.add(player1, block, monster)
def main():
    # Init pygame
    pygame.init()
    # Set screen
    backgrounds = ["background2.jpg", "background.jpg"]
    background = pygame.image.load(backgrounds[0])
    backgroundRect = background.get_rect()
    display = pygame.display.set_mode(background.get_size())
    # Creating FPS thingy
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    # Making levels  + Player
    score = Score()
    monster = Monster(30, 30, RANDOM)
    player = Player()
    level_1 = Level01(player, monster, display)
    level_2 = Level02(player, monster)
    # Choosing level
    levelList = []
    levelList.append(level_1)
    levelList.append(level_2)
    currentLevelNumber = 0
    # Game loop
    loop = True
    while loop == True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        player.move_right()
                    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        player.move_left()
                    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        player.move_up(currentLevel.platforms)
                    if event.key == pygame.KMOD_LSHIFT and event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        player.sprint()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and player.sprite_x_change < 0:
                    player.stop()
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and player.sprite_x_change > 0:
                    player.stop()
                if event.key == pygame.KMOD_LSHIFT:
                    player.sprite_x_change -= 10
        # Update things
        #monster.jump()
        if player.rect.x > 400:
            player.rect.x = 400
            currentLevel.scroll_x(-10)

        if player.rect.x >= WIDTH:
            player.rect.x = WIDTH
            currentLevel.scroll(0)

        if player.rect.y >= HEIGHT:
            main()

        if player.sprite_x_change < 0 and player.rect.x >= 120:
            currentLevel.scroll_x(0)


        if player.rect.left <= 120 and player.sprite_x_change < 0:
            player.rect.x = 120
            player.rect.left = 120
            currentLevel.scroll_x(10)
        '''
        if player.rect.y <= 300:
            if player.standing == False and player.sprite_y_change < 0:
                currentLevel.scroll_y(10)

        if currentLevel.shift_y > 0:
            y_speed = -4
            if player.standing == True and player.rect.y < 300:
                y_speed = 4
            print(currentLevel.shift_y)
            currentLevel.scroll_y(y_speed)
        '''
        currentLevel = levelList[currentLevelNumber]

        if currentLevel.shift_x > 0:
            currentLevel.scroll_x(currentLevel.shift_x * -1)

        display.blit(background, backgroundRect)
        player.updater(currentLevel.platforms, currentLevel.powerups, score, currentLevel.endPlatform)
        currentLevel.updater(display, score)
        # Refresh screen
        clock.tick(30)
        pygame.display.update()
    pygame.quit()
    loop = False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Make sure that the rect values of the block and the player are set correctly and collide. As far as I can tell, you are not setting the X/Y coordinates for the end block.

Comment: I set the x an y coordinates in the Level_01 class and am sure I did for Player too.

Comment: can you output the player's coordinates? Also, try to explicitly set the collision detection function (pygame.sprite.collide_rect()) as the fourth argument on spritecolide

Comment: Can anyone else help me! May it be because I use collision detection once so you can stand on it and another time so it detects when you have to go to the next level.

Comment: It seems I found the bug, for some daft reason you can't use collision detection twice on the same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I found the problem, for some daft reason you can't use collision detection twice on the same object. I used it once so that the player could stand on the block and another time so that you could go on to the next level!

Comment: Of course you can use collision detection twice, but in your case you're moving the rect away from the second rect after the first collision, so it can't work a second time.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it doesn't switch to the next level is that you change the position of the rect when it collides with a platform, so the `player.rect` gets moved out of the `blocks.rect` and therefore can't collide again when you call `spritecollide` with the `endPlatform` group.

A quick and dirty fix would be to check in the `for blocks in platforms_hit:` loops if the block is in the endPlatform group and then return `True`:

```
for blocks in platforms_hit:
    if blocks in endPlatform:
        score.add()
        return True
```

And then increase the `currentLevelNumber` in the `main` function if `True` is returned:

```
change_level = player.updater(currentLevel.platforms, currentLevel.powerups, score, currentLevel.endPlatform)
if change_level:
    currentLevelNumber += 1
```