# Pygame Zero Collision Detection Not Working

Tags: python, pgzero

I am a beginner trying to make a game that gives me a point whenever the ball is on the target (a white line) and I press my mouse. For some reason, the game gives me a point when I click the mouse even when the ball is not on the line.

This is my code:

```
import pgzrun
import pygame
import sys

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 800
score = 0
lives = 3

ball = Actor("redball")
ball.pos = 100,700

target = Actor("linetarget")
target.pos = 400,680

def draw():
    screen.clear()
    ball.draw()
    target.draw()
    

def update():
    ball.x += 10
    if ball.x == 800:
        ball.x = 100

def on_mouse_down():
    global score
    global lives
    if ball.colliderect(target):
        score += 1
        print(score)

    else:
        lives -= 1
        if lives == 0:
            sys.quit()

   


   


I am also accepting answers in Pygame. Please help!
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Collision detection not working in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33922546/collision-detection-not-working-in-pygame)

Comment: @naved196 The question is about collision detection in [Pygame Zero](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), but not about collision detection in [Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news)

Comment: The other questions don't help me. The Pygame Zero Read the Docs only has a sentence on colliderect(), and the other website doesn't help.

Comment: Do not use the [tag:pygame] tag here. Pygame Zero != Pygame. And that is the reason why the other question does not help you, because the other question is about Pygame.

Comment: Do you mean the tag?

Comment: So your problem is similar to this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65361582/how-to-get-the-correct-dimensions-for-a-pygame-rectangle-created-from-an-image/65361896#65361896

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine here, so a shot in the dark: you're using images with too much whitespace.

Note that when you create the actors you never specify their **sizes**, only positions:

```
ball = Actor("redball")
ball.pos = 100,700

target = Actor("linetarget")
target.pos = 400,680
```

The size is taken from the underlying image. If your `redball.png` or `linetarget.png` have too many empty pixels (transparent or not!), then `colliderect` will report collisions when the ball/line themselves are not touching.

My suggestion: open your images in an image editor (mspaint would do) and make sure the canvas fits the ball/line snuggly without empty borders around. You'll have to resize the image, not just select and delete white pixels.

And even in the best of cases, your collision will not be perfect for another reason: `colliderect` checks for [axis-aligned-bounding boxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box). That means your redball will always have empty spots around it (the rectangle corners), and your linetarget too if it's not perfectly vertical/horizontal (with 45 degrees being the worst case).

Comment: I tried to resize my images, but I can't  figure out how to get it right, so I just switched to drawn circles and rects. My new question is how to check for a collision between a draw circle and drawn rect?

Comment: @dgffdg I checked the documentation and couldn't find anything about it, you might have to compute it yourself. I recommend starting a new question.